# RavenDB ID getting messed up in code created index

Tags: ravendb, indexing

First off I'm just getting started with RavenDB so please be patient as I explain the issue. I'm trying to create my first map, map, reduce, transform index. Yeah I know I'm trying to do a lot but I have most of it working.

So first off I do this in my global.asax to make sure that all "ID" properties are used as the identifier on documents.

```
_documentStore.Conventions.FindIdentityProperty = p => p.Name == "ID";
```

OK now lets take a look at the index.

```
public class ProblemListViewIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<ProblemListView>
{
    public ProblemListViewIndex()
    {
        AddMap<Problem>(problems => from problem in problems
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ID = problem.ID,
                                        SolutionCount = 0,
                                    });

        AddMap<Solution>(solutions => from solution in solutions
                                      select new
                                      {
                                        ID = solution.ProblemID,
                                        SolutionCount = 1,
                                      });


        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.ID
                                into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    ID = g.Key,
                                    SolutionCount = g.Sum(x => x.SolutionCount),
                                };

        Indexes.Add(x => x.ID, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

        TransformResults = (database, results) => from result in results
                                                  let problem = database.Load<Problem>("problems/" + result.ID.ToString())
                                                  let user = database.Load<User>("users/" + problem.PostedByID.ToString())
                                                  select new
                                                  {
                                                      ID = result.ID,
                                                      PostedByID = problem.PostedByID,
                                                      PostedByName = user.DisplayName,
                                                      SolutionCount = result.SolutionCount,
                                                  };

    }
}
```

So everything looks good and when I test the index in the RavenDB website I get mixed results. I have duplicate projections. I have the two projections that I expect but two copies of them. Here are what the "ID" looks like on the projection results.

- problems/194
- problems/195
- 194
- 195

I'm confused but then I went back and looked at the "maps". My code translated into something different in the created index. Here is what the first map looks like when created initially.

```
docs.Problems
    .Select(problem => new {ID = problem.__document_id, SolutionCount = 0})
```

Even being new to RavenDB I see the problem. It's using the "__document_id" field when I want to use the "ID" field. I change the map in then save the index to the following.

```
docs.Problems
    .Select(problem => new {ID = problem.ID, SolutionCount = 0})
```

Once I do that my projection looks exactly as I expected and as I want it.

- 194
- 195

My question is what do I need to do in my code to get my index to create using "ID" over "__document_id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong here. I#ve put together a test using your code and I get what I have expected:

```
public class MultiMapWithTransformAndCustomId
{
    public class Problem
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string PostedByID { get; set; }
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Solution
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string ProblemID { get; set; }
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProblemListViewIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<ProblemListViewIndex.ReduceResult>
    {
        public class ReduceResult
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public int SolutionCount { get; set; }
            public string PostedByID { get; set; }
            public string PostedByName { get; set; }
        }

        public ProblemListViewIndex()
        {
            AddMap<Problem>(problems => from problem in problems
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            ID = problem.ID,
                                            SolutionCount = 0,
                                        });

            AddMap<Solution>(solutions => from solution in solutions
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              ID = solution.ProblemID,
                                              SolutionCount = 1,
                                          });


            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by result.ID
                                    into g
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ID = g.Key,
                                        SolutionCount = g.Sum(x => x.SolutionCount),
                                    };

            Indexes.Add(x => x.ID, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

            TransformResults = (database, results) => from result in results
                                                      let problem = database.Load<Problem>(result.ID.ToString())
                                                      let user = database.Load<User>(problem.PostedByID.ToString())
                                                      select new
                                                      {
                                                          ID = result.ID,
                                                          PostedByID = problem.PostedByID,
                                                          PostedByName = user.DisplayName,
                                                          SolutionCount = result.SolutionCount,
                                                      };

        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Can_do_simple_query()
    {
        using (var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            RunInMemory = true
        })
        {
            documentStore.Conventions.FindIdentityProperty = p => p.Name == "ID";
            documentStore.Initialize();

            using (var documentSession = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                documentSession.Store(new User {ID = "users/1", DisplayName = "Daniel"});
                documentSession.Store(new User {ID = "users/2", DisplayName = "Lang"});
                documentSession.Store(new Problem {ID = "problems/194", PostedByID = "users/1"});
                documentSession.Store(new Problem {ID = "problems/195", PostedByID = "users/2"});
                documentSession.Store(new Solution {ID = "solutions/1", ProblemID = "problems/194"});
                documentSession.Store(new Solution {ID = "solutions/2", ProblemID = "problems/194"});
                documentSession.Store(new Solution {ID = "solutions/3", ProblemID = "problems/195"});
                documentSession.SaveChanges();
            }

            new ProblemListViewIndex().Execute(documentStore);

            using (var documentSession = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                var results = documentSession.Query<ProblemListViewIndex.ReduceResult, ProblemListViewIndex>()
                    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
                    .ToList();

                Assert.Equal(2, results.Count);

                var daniel = results.First(x => x.PostedByName == "Daniel");
                var lang = results.First(x => x.PostedByName == "Lang");

                Assert.Equal("problems/194", daniel.ID);
                Assert.Equal("problems/195", lang.ID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You used strings as the ID. I am using integers.

Comment: Bobby, can you modify my code above so that it fails and send it to me? I will then fix this in RavenDB if possible.

Comment: I emailed you the updated code. I also edited your answer on accident. I jumped in too early this morning... need coffee.

Comment: I'm marking this an the answer but I still feel if RavenDB cannot handle integers as indexes then it shouldn't allow it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem too, I found a work around by adding another field to my Index, for example SolutionId, and set it's value to the same as the Id.

You should then be able to run queries against this value without any issues.

I asked the same question on here before, and apparently this is by design.

Comment: OH I cannot do that. I would go crazy... seriously I'm a clean code fanatic. If I had two field that were the same data always, I would not be able to sleep at night. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Daniel said, solution.ProblemID is an integer field.

The simplest solution is to change the solution map to be:

```
    ID = "problems/" + solution.ProblemID,
```

But I would strong suggest that you will use string references, instead of integer references, it will make everything simpler.

Comment: You do see the issue. RavenDB supposedly supports "int" keys but then mangles the indexes because it alters the key name. Why couldn't the index just leave the name alone? Why does RavenDB have to change the property name?

Comment: Oh and the management site will save it correctly. It just fails to create properly when creating from code.